# Is there any difference between these two functions in regard to efficiency?

Tags: algorithm

I encountered this two functions, is one more efficient than the other? what happens if I change `pow1(x^2, n/2) * x` to `return x*pow1(x^2, n/2)` in the first function?

```
int pow1(int x, int n){
 if(n==0)
  return 1; else
 if(n==1)
  return x; else
 if("n is odd")
  return pow1(x^2, n/2) * x ; else // change to return x*pow1(x^2, n/2) ?
 if("n is even")
  return pow1(x^2, n/2);
}

int pow2(int x, int n){
 p=1;
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
  p = p*x;
 }
 return p;
}
```

Comment: You may want to post this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/algorithms instead.

Comment: Why don't you test them out and measure the time for big `n`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is `O(logn)`, second is `O(n)`. So for sufficiently large `n`, first one is faster.

Comment: thanks, but how the x^2 been calculated in `return pow1(x^2, n/2)`? if the function itself is to calculate power..

Answer (score 2):

The second algorithm performs n multiplications. The first performs one multiplication for each *bit* in n; this makes it logarithmic in n. The method is called [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

> what happens if I change pow1(x^2, n/2) * x to return x*pow1(x^2, n/2) in the first function?
>   Nothing changes, as multiplication is commutative.

On a side node, is this in some programming language, or is it pseudocode? In a lot of languages, x^2 denotes a bitwise XOR between x and 2, not x squared. To square x, simply do x*x.